# Comunicación entre componentes en React no funciona

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Vengo aquí como mi último recurso, he tratado muchas cosas y no ha funcionado nada.

La cosa es que quiero hacer la función de `handleAuth` dentro del primer componente para no molestar con funciones y esas cosas al segundo.

Ahora bien, por alguna razón que desconozco, el segundo componente no recibe el valor por medio de `props.handle`.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

import AppHeader from "../../components/header/AppHeader";

Class AppHeaderControl extends PureComponent {
  handleAuth(){
    alert("click funciona");
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <AppHeader handleAuth={this.handleAuth} />
    );
  }
}
export default AppHeaderControl;
```

y

```
import React from "react";

import "./AppHeader.css";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
};

function AppHeader(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={classes.grow}>
            Dimensión Jerry
          </Typography>
          <button onClick={props.handleAuth}>Acceder</button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
AppHeader.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
export default withStyles(styles)(AppHeader);
```

Comment: Explica mejor lo que quieres lograr y el error que te genera por favor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia. Ya lo he actualizado

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que asignarle el el `scope` de tu clase al método, de lo contrario no lo encontrará llamándolo con el `this`.

Tienes dos opciones:

- Cambiar tu metodo a una `arrow function`
- Aplicarle un `bind` a tu método

> Te dejo los dos opciones anteriores

**Cambiar tu metodo a una `arrow function`**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

import AppHeader from "../../components/header/AppHeader";

Class AppHeaderControl extends PureComponent {

  // cambiaremos tu método a arrow function
  handleAuth = (e) => {
    alert("click funciona");
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <AppHeader handleAuth={this.handleAuth} />
    );
  }
}
export default AppHeaderControl;
```

**Aplicar un `bind` a tu método**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

import AppHeader from "../../components/header/AppHeader";

Class AppHeaderControl extends PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    // aplicarle el bind inicializando tu clase
    this.handleAuth = this.handleAuth.bind(this)
  }

  // Tu método
  handleAuth(){
    alert("click funciona");
  }

  render(){

    // hacer e bind desde aca o en el constructor
    return(
      <AppHeader handleAuth={this.handleAuth} />
    );
  }
}
export default AppHeaderControl;
```

*Espero haberte ayudado.*

Comment: Vaya, no entiendo porqué no funciona, probé con el primer metodo, pero nada.

Comment: Intenta: remover AppHeader.propTypes, crear tu función AppHeader en una clase extendida de React.

Comment: De ninguna forma, creo que lo mejor será crear la función dentro del mismo componente y no enviarlo como propiedad. Hace poco empeze con esto de React y he leído que es mucho mejor separar componentes (UI) de containers(toda la logica).

Comment: el problema lo tiene como esta creando el componente react del Header, ya tienes medio paso guialo @MerlingSamuelSobalvarro

Answer (score 0):

Al final he optado por descomponer el botón y crear un componente para él, además así me será más facil. Dejo el código por si alguien tiene el mismo problema

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

class LoginButton extends PureComponent {
  handleAuth = () => {
    alert("obo");
  };

  render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.handleAuth}>Acceder</Button>;
  }
}

export default LoginButton;
```

Muchisimas gracias!